# Printer dropping packets while in standby mode

Tags: switch, timeout, printer, packetloss

We have an HP LaserJet Pro 400 M401n connected to a Brocade ICX6450-24P that is having some intermittent connection issues while it is in standby mode. I have a feeling there might be some electrical interference on the line due to the way it was ran, but I'm not sure if this is the way it would manifest itself.

While the printer is "ready", it will respond to looping pings for the entire time it is in that state with 0% packet loss (1 hour). Once it goes into standby, it will timeout every 5-6 pings until a print job pulls it back to ready. Additionally, navigating around the management webpage will stop the timeouts as long as I am actively clicking on links.

We have several of these printers and none of them act like this, and we even have another printer on this same switch without these problems. That said, it doesn't really seem to be causing any issues at the moment. I just don't want to leave it as is if this is a problem with the line that may come back to bite us.

Has anyone had something similar occur, or does this sound like something that could be caused by interference?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If it were interference, if would cause issues constantly. When in standby mode, it seems reasonable that the CPU would not be as responsive to pings. If it's not causing issues with that actual function of the printer, then don't worry about it.

Comment: You're probably right. This is at a remote site that we just added to our domain this week and don't have easy physical access to, so I am super paranoid about any networking anomalies out there right now. I will just let it be unless it ends up causing actual problems.